# How to unlock template elements in iWork Pages to edit them?

Tags: macos, iwork, iwork-pages

I'm using one of those nice default templates. But for some reason, some of the elements can't be moved around. They don't have those square boxes that can be dragged to change size. The squares appear like small **x** symbols and all things like background color are set, but "grayed out". I guess I could unlock them somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

You're correct; you seek "Unlock" in the "Arrange" menu (Command-Option-L).

Comment: THANK YOU. Other answers I've seen (including iWork help for templates) suggest the blue handles indicate it's a "master object" which must be enabled for editing with Format->Advanced->Make Master Objects Selectable, but that option is greyed out for me. "Unlock" was what I needed.